# Get all children categories of a specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Currently I have this to get children of a category:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$childrenIds = $category->getResource()->getChildren($category, true);
```

However, it will get only active children. Is there a way to get all children of a specific category, including disabled categories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

user76757,You `cannot get inactive  because of  Flat system is enable for category`.
The setting is  enable at  admin  In order to see this option, go to `Magento admin section and click on: System -> Config -> Catalog and Frontend. "Use Flat Catalog Product". make it No then indexing  from index management`.There fore you can all inactive  category.

Magento is use the flat system for product and category,instead of taking the eav data from one table the data is taken from one table.see at http://inchoo.net/magento/flat-tables-in-magento-and-product-collection/

You can the code how magento write it logic.
**File:app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php**

```
 protected function _construct()
{
    // If Flat Data enabled then use it but only on frontend
    $flatHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat');
    if ($flatHelper->isAvailable() && !Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() && $flatHelper->isBuilt(true)
        && !$this->getDisableFlat()
    ) {
        $this->_init('catalog/category_flat');
        $this->_useFlatResource = true;
    } else {
        $this->_init('catalog/category');
    }
}
```

So you can not get disable categories when  flat enable .

**Alternative Solution:** for getting `inactive and active children categories` try this

**$category->getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive();**

See Alan Strom [blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_flat_collection_chaos)

Comment: $allChildren = $category->getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive()